# Grub commandline has multiple identical options

Tags: grub2

I'm using `Linux ... 3.19.0-31-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:04:02 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

In the file `etc\default\grub` I find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw nomdmonddf nomdmonisw"
```

Is it safe to remove the duplicate/triplicate entries `nomdmonddf nomdmonisw`?

Comment: Since those aren't present by default, you must have added them (directly or indirectly).

Comment: I'm absolutely sure I didn't. I think they appeared there on the upgrade to 15.04.

Comment: Affected by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1291434?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](http://ewen.mcneill.gen.nz/blog/entry/2015-06-14-ubuntu-lucid-to-trust-in-two-larger-steps/) has the following to say about the issue:

Two new RAID-related options appeared in the kernel options with Ubuntu 14.04 -- `nomdmonddf` and `nomdmonisw`. They appear to be underdocumented, and basically only relate to Ubuntu. AFAICT they relate to the plan to change from using `dmraid` to `mdadm` to assemble RAID devices; but I've been using mdadm for years.

The "nom nom nom" duplication seems to be caused by:

`/etc/default/grub.d/dmraid2mdadm.cfg` containing:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT nomdmonddf nomdmonisw"`
which unilaterally appends them to the config if the `mdadm` package is installed, even if they are already there ( :-( ); and

`dpkg-reconfigure grub-pc`, which picks up those arguments and puts them into `/etc/default/grub`, so that they're baked in for another round of adding them

`update-grub` also adding them onto the command line written into `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` even if they're already there in the text coming from `/etc/default/grub`.

[...]

There are some Ubuntu bugs #1291434 and #1318351 about this, so it might eventually be implemented better. Making the "ensure these parameters are present" idempotent -- so it only adds them once -- would seem like a good start!